# how to pass value to a modal?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I have a problem , I own a view that contains a form and this form contains a list , I need to get some items from this list that are " hidden " and show them the modal , but I still do not know how to do this , I've been reading some items but it seems no fits in my case , detail : this hidden item is actually another list that appears also as a form, use case: User selects a list of the order , from that order I get the products has it and display the modal , the structure of my list is as follows: ListOrder [ ] listProduct , code . . :

Entity:

```
namespace Teste.Models
{
    public class Order
    {
        public Int64 order { get; set; }
        public String supply { get; set; }
        public List<Product> listProduct { get; set;}
}

namespace Teste.Models
    {
        public class Product
        {
            public Int64 cod { get; set; }
            public String name { get; set; }

    }
```

view

```
 @model Test.Models.Order

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Teste</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        @Styles.Render("~/Content/bootstrap.css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <style>
            th {
                height: 10px;
            }
        </style>
<script>
        $(function () {

            $("#dialog").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false,

                });

                $(".opener").click(function () {
                    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                });
        });
    </script>
        </head>
    <body>
            <div id="divbody">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        </nav>
                @using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Cab", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <div class="table-responsive" id="table">
                        <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped" cellspacing="0">
                            <thead style="position:static">
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="font-size:10px">SELECT</th>
                                    <th style="font-size:10px">CONTACT</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th style="font-size:10px">SUPPLY</th>
                                    <th style="font-size:10px">ORDER</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.listOrder.Count(); i++)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center" height="2px">@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.listOrder[i].isEdit, new { @onclick = "habilit(" + i + ")", @id = "c" + i })</td>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("getFornecedor", "MyController")" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone-alt"></i>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("sendEmail", "MyController")" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listOrder[i].supply, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "18px", @class = "form-controlSupply" }) </td>
                                    <td height="2px"> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.listOrder[i].order, new { @readonly = "readonly", @size = "75px", @class = "form-controlOrder" }) </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Salve" id="btn" disabled="disabled" class="btn btn-small btn-primary" />
                }
<div id="dialog" title="Dados do Fornecedor">
                        <p>Teste dados fornecedor</p>
                    </div>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Are you wanting a dropdownlist to select from?

Comment: I see you've included jQuery - it can do all sorts of stuff, like replace the contents of a div. Try searching a little more, I`m sure the answer will appear!